# How to open and close my UIToolbar on swipe gestures in IOS?

Tags: ios5, uitoolbar, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am new to IOS app development, so please help me out. There is a toolbar in my app where i am adding some buttons, i want this toolbar to appear at the bottom left corner as a button or something when i swipe(right) on it the toolbar should open and when i swipe i opposite direction(left) on the toolbar the toolbar should close and with some animations like translation to the left/right.

I have created toolbar and i dont know how to continue, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.